# Things to take care after setting up Mac OS X on a virtual box on a windows 7 host for developing RoR apps?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, virtualbox

I am planning to setup Mac OS X on a virtual box on a windows 7 host for developing RoR applications since i heard that there are some limitations to developing RoR on windows.I am planning to use TextMate and iTerm for my development.Other than setting up Mac OS X is there  anything (like change some settings)  i should take care to build the web applications on RoR using Mac OS X on a virtual box.In other words after setting up the Mac OS X on the virtual box shall i proceed as we usually do on a Mac OS X host or do i need to tweak anything to make my RoR apps work.Also let me know if this is not a good idea.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you get it to work in virtual machine, not a bad idea. No pitfalls I can think of, except, perhaps, speed.

However, linux (pretend I said Ubuntu) is even better environment for Ruby on Rails development and it installs great in VM.

Just a thing to consider. Only thing is that VIM takes a bit more to get used to.

Comment: Is the speed reduced significantly on the Virtual box?

Comment: Should be ok for development.

Comment: Thanks for your answer .I will be going ahead with Mac OS X most probably.I will let you know my experience on that.

Comment: Just one more question, does linux on Virtualbox require hardware virtualisation to be present?

Comment: I will be going with ubuntu for my development.Thanks for your help.

Comment: There is a fine editor called Redcar that is written in Ruby and is cross-platform. You could check it out.